# capifony deploy issue with symfony 2

Tags: git, symfony, ssh, capistrano, capifony

I have to instance of my application with two stage each on the server.

instance1 - master
          - staging

instance2 - master
          - staging

To deploy to instance 1 I use master1 branch and master2 for instance2.

everything was working well until I changed the root password on my server. 
I can deploy from master1 branch but not from master2.
what is weird is that from my local pc to the server as well as from the server to git I use ssh keys to authenticate. I really do not understand why changing the password brought that issue.

this is the error i get

```
executing command
command finished in 653ms

*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back

command finished in 133ms
failed: "sh -c 'sh -c '\\''cd /var/www/instance2/staging/releases/20130904114214 && php app/console assets:install web --env=prod'\\'''" on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: Add `logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL` to your deployment file to get more information on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you elnur for your quick response. I already have the logger level set to max.

I fixed the issue. to find the problem, I ran php app/console assets:install web on my local. because it is the command that fails on the server. this helped me see that one of my class does not have the same name as the file that contains it. I wonder how it worked on local...